# How to display a message beside respective input in an html table?

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I have created a table inside a form and one column consists of input elements. I have written a JavaScript function to validate each input. If invalid, the corresponding error message should be displayed beside respective input. In my case, for any input, the error message is always displayed beside the first input.

I tried using `<div>` and `<span>` tags with respective id values. For every invalid input the error message is displayed beside the first input and not the corresponding input.

Html table

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>S.No</td>
        <td>Particulars</td>
        <td>Amount</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>01</td>
        <td>Annual Rent (Only of residential unit not owned by employer)</td>
        <td><input type="number" name="ann_rent"><div id="ar_invalid"></div></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>02</td>
        <td>Mediclaim (U/s. 80D of I.T. Act)</td>
        <td><input type="number" name="medi"><div id="medi_invalid"></div></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
         <td>03</td>
         <td>Interest paid for Home Loan</td>
         <td><input type="number" name="home_int"><div id="home_invalid"></div></td>                        
    </tr>


     <tr>
          <td>04</td>
          <td>National Pension</td>
          <td><input type="number" name="nat_pen"><div id="pen_invalid"></div></td>                   
     </tr>
</table>
```

Javascript function

```
function validate() {
var a,b,c,d;
a = document.getElementsByName("ann_rent")[0].value;
b = document.getElementsByName("medi")[0].value;
c = document.getElementsByName("home_int")[0].value;
d = document.getElementsByName("nat_pen")[0].value;
if(!a || a < 0) {
    document.getElementById("ar_invalid").innerHTML = text;          
    return false;
}

if(!b || b < 0) {
    document.getElementById("medi_invalid").innerHTML = text;
    return false;
}

if(!c || c < 0) {
    document.getElementById("home_invalid").innerHTML = text;
    return false;
}

if(!d || d < 0) {
    document.getElementById("pen_invalid").innerHTML = text;
    return false;
}
}
```

Table is inside this form

```
<form action="process_form.php" method="post" onSubmit="return validate();">
```

CSS

```
td, th {
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

table {
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    width: 100%;
}
```

If user enters a negative value in input name="home_int", then the error message should be displayed beside input home_int. But actually, the error message is getting displayed beside input name="ann_rent". This situation is occurring for every input.

Comment: have you tried with "this" ?   `var $this = $(this);     var row = $this.closest("tr");`

Comment: your "error <td>" element after amount is overlapping the third "<td> amount"

Comment: @gopigorantala "error<td>" is going to be empty inititally. How do I assign space to it so it doesn't overlap?

Comment: you don't have your error td element for each child entries.. you need to add a new td element for showing up an error message

Answer (score 0):

use th for headers. Add a new td for the error message

```
    <table>
            <tr>
                <th>S.No</th>
                <th>Particulars</th>
                <th>Amount</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>01</td>
                <td>Annual Rent (Only of residential unit not owned by employer)</td>
                <td><input type="number" name="ann_rent"></td>
                <td><div id="ar_invalid"></div></td>
            </tr>
    </table>
```

**css**

```
table td, table th {
  padding: 20px;
  border-spacing: 10px;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Comment: Even now, the error message is displayed in the 1st row and not in the row where the error actually occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a button to submit for form validation which goes something like this:

```
    <input type="submit" name="s" value="ds"/>
```

What happening is when your function gets inside the first if it then returns false and form will not be submitted so the other ifs wont perform any action in this situation so  when you type any negative number in the first if, other ifs whether they are positive or negative wont work and the code will execute the message in the first div

but it will work and will show the message in the desired div if you will only put a negative number inside a specific textbox and all before will be positive

Answer (score 0):

Change the "errors" divs to similar as below so you can have a simpler javascript code:

HTML:

```
<form action="/" method="post" onSubmit="return validate();">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>S.No</td>
        <td>Particulars</td>
        <td>Amount</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>01</td>
        <td>Annual Rent (Only of residential unit not owned by employer)</td>
        <td><input type="number" name="ann_rent"><div id="ann_rent_invalid"></div></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>02</td>
        <td>Mediclaim (U/s. 80D of I.T. Act)</td>
        <td><input type="number" name="medi"><div id="medi_invalid"></div></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
         <td>03</td>
         <td>Interest paid for Home Loan</td>
         <td><input type="number" name="home_int"><div id="home_int_invalid"></div></td>                        
    </tr>


     <tr>
          <td>04</td>
          <td>National Pension</td>
          <td><input type="number" name="nat_pen"><div id="nat_pen_invalid"></div></td>                   
     </tr>
  </table>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

and in javascript:

```
function validate() {
  var text = "error";
  var required = ["ann_rent", "medi", "home_int", "nat_pen"];
  var errors = 0;

  required.forEach(function(element) {
    var toselect = element + "_invalid";
    var reqV = document.getElementsByName(element)[0].value;
    if(!reqV || reqV < 0) {
      document.getElementById(toselect).innerHTML = text;
      errors++;
    } else {
      document.getElementById(toselect).innerHTML = null; 
    }
  });

  if(errors > 0){
     return false;
  }
}
```